# Windows doesn't generate thumbs.db file in my network folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbs.db

So, I have a network folder with an image and thumbnail view turned on, but I still can't see the thumbs.db file in that folder. I have all setting 'Show hidden files' checked, including the on with system files. Still don't see thumbs.db file.
Any clues what can help?  Image is in .PNG format.
I've seen a thread where someone had similar issue and someone pointed out that it might be because it was handled by explorer extension and it just caches the image preview and doesn't create a thumbs.db file.

Comment: Do you actually open the image with Photos app, or have show preview enabled in explorer itself? Both should trigger the creation of thumbs.db, unless GPO disables this for network shares.

Comment: I tried both and still don't see the file.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 no longer creates Thumbs.db files within folders at all – the last OS version that did so was Windows XP.

All later versions use a central cache at `~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`.

Comment: You mean `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`.

Comment: Not true. At home, my windows 10 professional creates the thumbs.db on my network share and I have to explicitly disable it using a GPO.